# Improve this update query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've been struggling to run this query.  It takes a really long time.
Its MySQL Innodb.  The fields I am using are indexed.  Its on a pretty beefy server with around 10gig allocated to the innodb pool config thing.

```
UPDATE TEMP_account_product p
JOIN products_temp c ON (c.`some_id` = p.`old_someid`)
SET p.`product` = c.id
WHERE p.product IS NULL;
```

The thing to note here is that both tables contain around 900,000 rows.  this line brings back around 800,000 records (`WHERE p.product IS NULL;`)

I have a feeling I'm kinda screwed here but thought Id try anyway.

Comment: Can you add table definitions and any indexes please

Comment: And EXPLAIN <query> can by really helpful.

Comment: @mvf: There's no `EXPLAIN` for `UPDATE` statement in MySQL :(

Comment: As you're updating over 90% of the table, you may be better advised to create a new table, write an `INSERT INTO x SELECT a, b, c FROM x JOIN y`, then rename the tables. In short, it may be better to start again than to change what you've got. But that will depend on foreign key constraints, etc. *[But either way, if the join is taking ages, any update or insert will take ages. Check if you have appropriate indexes to improve the join, and create them if you don't.]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that possible reasons of slow execution of such type of request can be:

- **MOST probable** - you have an INDEX(es) on updated field and that request is updating lot of rows - in that case MySQL will need to do a lot of work rebuilding that INDEX(es) during UPDATE. In that case just DROP the INDEX(es) before request, and later recreate it (if needed).
- JOIN is slow (you can check it by select with that JOIN) - i.e. join is done w/o INDEXES. Add indexes in that case.
- slow filtering of WHERE (i.e. MySQL make a full scan to filter), - you can check how fast it is by select with same filter.

Comment: Just selecting with join filter is taking a really long time to complete.

Comment: Then take a look at EXPLAIN of that SELECT ;)

Comment: @Tyler . . . I would suggest working on the SELECT first.  You can always put the results in a temporary table for the update.

Comment: @mvf  What am I looking for in the EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running it in batches, so that you don't need to rely on the query plan to decide not to being the entire result set into memory before it starts doing the updates. Add something like LIMIT 1000 to the query, and then run it until the number of affected rows is zero (technique depends on your environment, but I think it could be done in SQL).

**UPDATE, *this is not a valid option (as-is)*.**

Sure enough, I overlooked this in the [UPDATE docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax ... In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: Cannot use LIMIT with that query "Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT"

Comment: Sure 'nough. Edit shows future-finders the issue. Kept the answer un-deleted for future reference.